# How to get sum of one week before dates in between date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

To calculate average cost of goods, we are taking one week data from invoice date. Now in Stored Procedure i tried this

```
    i.InvoiceDate  BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-6, @StartDate) AND @StartDate
```

It is not right because it is showing 6 days before the data for all dates.

For example if i given the dates startdate:'12/01/2014' and enddate:'12/10/2014'
average cost should be calculated as sum(invoiceAmount)/Sum(Quntity)

```
1 week before for '12/01/2014',
1 week before for '12/02/2014',
1 week before for '12/03/2014',
1 week before for '12/04/2014',
1 week before for '12/05/2014',
1 week before for '12/06/2014',
1 week before for '12/07/2014',
1 week before for '12/08/2014',
1 week before for '12/09/2014',
1 week before for '12/10/2014',
```

how to Achieve this.. Can anybody help me on this

Comment: Not clear what you are asking? Do you want average cost for each day or each week between given date range ?

Comment: I need 1 week before data for each date, between date range

Comment: need to see more of the query or the schema/tables involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Table & Data :

```
Create Table MyTable
(
  invoiceDate date,
  invoiceAmount int,
  Quantity int
)

insert into MyTable Select '11/24/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/25/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/26/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/27/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/28/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/29/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '11/30/2014',100,10
insert into MyTable Select '12/01/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/02/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/03/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/04/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/05/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/06/2014',100,5
insert into MyTable Select '12/07/2014',100,5
```

Query :

```
Select i.invoiceDate,Avg(p.Avg) from MyTable as i
cross apply (
  Select sum(invoiceAmount)/Sum(Quantity) as Avg from MyTable
  where invoiceDate  BETWEEN DATEADD(wk,-1, i.invoiceDate) AND i.invoiceDate
)as p
where Datepart(mm,i.invoiceDate)=12
group by i.invoiceDate
```

See here [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f861/5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I tried this, but it is showing one week before the start date only, it is correct for first date only. and wrong for the rest of the dates..

Comment: Can you please provide sample date & desired output?

Comment: I think he needs week grouping for each date in given date range.

Comment: I think I have got you question, give me sometime

Comment: Sample dates sdate:'12/01/2014' and edate:'12/03/2014'.

Comment: Please take a look now, check example also.

Comment: Sample dates sdate:'12/01/2014' and edate:'12/03/2014'.
I need out put like this:
Date                          avg
------                          -----
12/01/2014              24.35(this is the avg amount of '26/11/2013' to '12/01/2014')
12/02/2014              26.54(this is the avg amount of '27/11/2013' to '12/02/2014')
12/03/2014              25.31(this is the avg amount of '28/11/2013' to '12/03/2014')

Comment: Please check now, example was having one issue. corrected

Comment: In this example values are not correct 
2014-12-01 11
2014-12-02 12
2014-12-03 13
2014-12-04 15
2014-12-05 16
2014-12-06 17
2014-12-07 18

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72904/discussion-between-ak47-and-subbarao-gaddam).

Comment: Thank you so much finally i got the answer by doing simple change of your query,1) commenting of invoice date, 2) convert to decimal of sum(invoiceamount) and sum(qty)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Days INT

DECLARE @intFlag INT

SET @intFlag = 1

SET @Days = SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS DiffDate

WHILE (@intFlag <=@Days)
BEGIN 

    Select @StartDate, sum(invoiceAmount)/Sum(Quntity) 
    FROM TableName Where Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -6, @StartDate) AND @StartDate

SET  @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate )   
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1

END
```